# how to enable cors on localhost/server

Tags: php, cors, pdf.js

I'm trying to load a pdf from external server and now I'm getting this error in console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://mobile.switchitapp.com/uploads/pdf/userGuide.pdf. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://appsdata2.cloudapp.net' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

How to get rid of this error? I have tried a lot but nothing has worked for me till now please help me out

thanks :)

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PDF.js Learning</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/1.8.472/pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/1.8.472/pdf.worker.js"></script>
    <script>
        // URL of PDF document
        var url = "https://mobile.switchitapp.com/uploads/pdf/userGuide.pdf";

        // Asynchronous download PDF
        PDFJS.getDocument(url)
            .then(function(pdf) {
                return pdf.getPage(1);
            })
            .then(function(page) {
                // Set scale (zoom) level
                var scale = 1.5;

                // Get viewport (dimensions)
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                // Get canvas#the-canvas
                var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');

                // Fetch canvas' 2d context
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                // Set dimensions to Canvas
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                // Prepare object needed by render method
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };

                // Render PDF page
                page.render(renderContext);
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `var url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://mobile.switchitapp.com/uploads/pdf/userGuide.pdf"` and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/42744707#42744707 for an explanation

Comment: doesn't work either also I want to do this on my server I have tried enable cors thing but I don't know where I'm wrong.

Comment: The problem is that the https://mobile.switchitapp.com site doesn’t send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header in its responses. Is that your site? If not then there’s nothing you can do to fix it other than making the request through a proxy as in my other comment.

Comment: nope it's not mine site actually in google gview it's working fine so I want the same thing to be done on my server like google is doing. can you please provide the insight behind this? It will be helpful for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Try var url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://mobile.switchit‌​app.com/uploads/pdf/‌​userGuide.pdf"
>
> doesn't work either also

The suggested solution is the comment shall work. Please see:

```js
// URL of PDF document
        var url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" +
 "https://mobile.switchitapp.com/uploads/pdf/userGuide.pdf";

        // Asynchronous download PDF
        PDFJS.getDocument(url)
            .then(function(pdf) {
                return pdf.getPage(1);
            })
            .then(function(page) {
                // Set scale (zoom) level
                var scale = 1.5;

                // Get viewport (dimensions)
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                // Get canvas#the-canvas
                var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');

                // Fetch canvas' 2d context
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                // Set dimensions to Canvas
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                // Prepare object needed by render method
                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };

                // Render PDF page
                page.render(renderContext);
            });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/1.8.472/pdf.js"></script>
 <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: yes its working but what about if I want to do on my server.

Answer (score -1):

Enabling CORS on localhost is no different from enabling on any remote server. See https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Your problem that you cannot do that for remote server, and you really need to enable CORS there instead of localhost. You question is somewhat invalid.